# How to find the largest value in a table using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to determine the largest value of any data in an entire table using SQL. Note that I really mean an entire table, not just one column or row. The entire table is type varchar, and the goal is to determine what the largest value is (varchar 255, varchar 100, etc).

Example:

```
Name  |  ID
John  |   1
Jake  |   2
James |   3
```

Should return "James" because it is the largest value in the whole table. I also want the length.

Comment: Sample data? What have you tried?

Comment: Could you provide the table structrue please?

Comment: What is a "byte value"?  Your question doesn't make any sense.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Database tables are not spreadsheets, despite some superficial similarities. In a database, rows and columns are *distinctly* different things. If you want unstructured data in a 2-d grid, why not *use* a spreadsheet?

Comment: This is quite the bizarre requirement. What about datatypes like uniqueidentifier which have a fixed length. Or what about varbinary(max)? What are you going to to about ties?

Comment: So name 'James' is taking more bytes than ID 3, you think? If the ID column is defined as `BIGINT`, then it may be different. This really is a strange task. I wonder what it would be good for to find that largest value.

Comment: I realize that databases and spreadsheets are not the same thing, that has nothing to do with the question. I also realize it is a bizarre requirement, but stating that is not helpful either. When given an entire table of data, is there a SQL command the returns the largest value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all columns are varchar, you could UNPIVOT the table into one column, and then select the TOP 1 value ordered by LEN() DESC.

Note that if the columns have different lengths, you will need to cast them to all have the same length so they can be unpivoted together.

Answer (score 0):

You can get byte size by using

```
select max(datalength(col0)+datalength(col1)+datalength(col2)...) from table
```

Be wary this might be an expensive query

Comment: ...expensive query *

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write the query for one particular table:

```
select top(1) value 
from
(
  select datalength(col1) as len, cast(col1 as varchar(max)) as value from mytable
  union all
  select datalength(col2) as len, cast(col2 as varchar(max)) as value from mytable
  union all
  ...
) data
order by len desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Look up the internet for data types and how much byte they take For example int = 4 byte.
If you have types like varchar or nvarchar
use `max(len(column))+2` the length will give you the byte it's basicly the same

Comment: I specifically stated I did not want it for just a column, so this is not helpful.

Comment: You can use this for all columns in that table as I said if it's int your column size will be 4 byte doesn't matter what the value is and if type is char it's the length if it's varchar or nvarchar length+2
If you can find 1 column like this you can find all